# grep: /proc/version : Permission Denied

Tags: linux, grep, visual-studio-code, version, proc

I wanted to run vscode as non root user so I switched to another user by "su - username" and run "code" but it gave an error "grep : /proc/version : permission denied" Help me out !!!

Comment: Please try this : `$ cat /proc/version` .

Comment: It's gives " cat : proc/version : permission denied "

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any problem with reinstalling VS Code, then just `sudo apt remove code` and install code-oss using terminal: `sudo apt install code-oss`. VS Code - Open Source Software.